# Script for ubuntu with 2 IPv4 so that auto choose which direction to go through

Tags: scripting, ip, routing, port-forwarding, ipv4

I have a PC with two IPs, for an internal network with IP 10.X.X.X and another for an external network with IP 192.168.X.X
I have two network configuration profiles, one for each. If I am on 10.x.x.x and I ping a terminal connected to 192.168.x.x it does not respond and vice versa, I have to change my profile first and then it responds to the ping.
Is there a script that allows you to direct which IP to go through, depending on whether it is 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x?

Thank you so much

Comment: How big is each network/LAN?  If I read this right, you want to connect a Class A IP address to a Class C IP address.  Can you possibly explain your topology?

Comment: @eyoung100, I'm not sure classful network design terminology is particularly relevant beyond the potentially available address space. This could simply be a home or SOHO network that's segmented as the 192.168.x.x external suggests, a lot of home/SOHO routers force you into particular address space.

Comment: You say your PC is connected to both networks, are you _on_ that PC trying to ping from one range to the other or on some other device? Does that PC simply have 2 NICs or is it set up to route between the 2 networks. If it's not set up to route, is there a router somewhere that you think should be able to talk from one network to the other? Only routers (including PCs/servers/etc configured as routers) can communicate between networks. By definition, if you can route between networks, you are a router. It sounds like you are trying to configure your PC _as_ a router. What OS is your PC?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RedAnne I asked him to explain his topology/aka classful terminology for the exact reason you gave a longer than normal comment about PC/servers etc. Configured as Routers.  I need to know the topology in order to either add or remove a Level3 Switch or Bridge or Reconfigure the Devices connected to the PC to either exist in Class A (10.x.x.x) or Class C(192.168.1).  Even a SOHO network device allows a DHCP class change if the configuration allows it, otherwise we configure the device that is configurable into the Class  of the device that isn't

Comment: @eyoung100, but the classful terminology is unnecessary, it has been deprecated for decades for good reason. The important thing here is what the OP means by having two IPs, if they're on a Windows/Linux laptop and one of those is a wireless NIC, then routing between the two is possible but not trivial. If they're on a mac, it is trivial. If OP is on a different device and thinks the device with two IPs is somehow connecting the two networks, automagically, they simply don't understand routing and switching enough and we need to back up.

Comment: @RedAnne Thank You for making me [look here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19840/does-cidr-really-do-away-with-ip-address-classes)